# MVC htaccess rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Hello i have problem with my htaccess configuration in my own mvc. IDK what i do wrong? All time i have this message 500:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

I want to make url rewrite to index.
Try to do somthing like this

> www.example.com/index.php/controller/method/param
>
> www.example.com/index.php?url=controler

My .htaccess look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l 

RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?url=$l [QSA,L]
```

What i do wrong ?? I read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html and do how is there explained.

Comment: "More information about this error may be available in the server error log." — So look there and see what it says.

Comment: @Quentin Well, I hope he also read this in the manual. "*Finally, before proceeding, be sure to configure mod_rewrite's log level to one of the trace levels using the LogLevel directive. Although this can give an overwhelming amount of information, it is indispensable in debugging problems with mod_rewrite configuration, since it will tell you exactly how each rule is processed.*" https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html

Comment: Is it strange that you already have index.php in the source URL. I thought the idea of rewriting URLs for MVC was to translate a URL from this, `http://www.example.com/controller/method/foo/bar/baz/buz/`, to a substitution in the general form of  `http://www.example.com/index.php?c=controller&m=method&p=/foo/bar/baz/buz/`. Or, more simply, `http://www.example.com/index.php?path=/controller/method/foo/bar/baz/buz/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check these configuration directives if your *.htaccess* hidden file is in the main root:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^index\.php/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/method/param$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It will rewrite *www.example.com/index.php/**$var**/method/param* into *www.example.com/index.php?url=**$var*** but make sure that your *.htaccess* file is in the main root.

Comment: How is there going to be an underscore, when that is not a valid URL character? He might be better off doing somethign like `(.+)`, instead of trying to specify a specific class of characters.

Answer (score 4):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

This one should works

```
http://www.mysite.com/stats
```

=>

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?url=stats
```

Comment: okay this work but look. when i put in index.php test var : $url = $_GET['url']; echo $url; this only work on index.php?url=test . When i try index.php/test/other he give me " Notice: Undefined index $url". Whay

Comment: Note `%{REQUEST_URI} !-l` is for Apache 2.2. Use `%{REQUEST_URI} !-L` in Apache 2.4.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an error on your last line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?url=$l [QSA,L]
```

It should be:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

In other words change the $l (the letter el) to a $1 (the number one). Also, you probably want your $ after the parentheses to close the line.

Comment: I know it is common, but I wonder why `url` is used so frequently in the substitution, when in fact `$1` is not a URL, but a path component.