# Need help for mod_rewrite rewriterule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

this is my **.htaccess**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
#RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?main=$0
</IfModule>
```

It works nice for hyperlinks like http://www.test.de/Contact, but i want to **add more parameter**, for example:

```
http://www.test.de/Categorie/A/1        index.php?main=$0&sub1=$1&sub2=$2
```

Can someone help me to define the RewriteRule? **Thanks!**

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC htaccess rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314756/mvc-htaccess-rewrite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
#RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?main=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)$ index.php?main=$1&sub1=$2
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)$ index.php?main=$1&sub1=$2&sub2=$3
</IfModule>
```

Try this out. The problem with your rewrite rule is that it only matches word characters (characters that make up a word). It terminates at the first /. Plus you have a $ at the end which isn't absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thanks just had to edit the $-Variables:


`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
#RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?main=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)$ index.php?main=$1&sub1=$2
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)$ index.php?main=$1&sub1=$2&sub2=$3
</IfModule>`

Comment: Didn't catch the pattern references, they do indeed start at 1, 0 usually refers to the whole match.