# seo friendly url issue using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having a problem with htaccess.

My non seo friendly url looks like this

```
http://localhost/mybb/index.php?url=login/register
```

and the code is

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mybb/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And it returns `http://localhost/mybb/login/register` which is absolutely fine now I am trying to modify the url which will look like this

```
http://localhost/mybb/login/register/step/1
```

And the original url is

```
http://localhost/mybb/index.php?url=login/register&step=1
```

I tried with this

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1&step=1$ [QSA,L]
```

it worked with the url which has step as param but if there is no 'step' in url then it doesn't work.Is it possible to add the /step/1 in the seo url only if the actual url contains the param called 'step'.Thanks

**SOLVED**

The last line should be

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?url=$0&step=$2 [L,QSA]
```

And turn off `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l`

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314756/mvc-htaccess-rewrite) is what you're looking for...

Comment: Thanks. Actually that is what I am doing now but I want to add a extra parameter that is .../register/step/1

Comment: Pretty close but I think I am missing a minor thing but not able to track what.

Comment: It's all good now. Thanks.