# When using ASP.NET MVC, is there a requirement to set up a URL Rewrite rule such as in Apache's .htaccess?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I'm coming from doing things by hand in PHP MVC, and I always had to do things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314756/mvc-htaccess-rewrite),

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^index\.php/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/method/param$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Thus far I haven't seen that using ASP.NET MVC, but haven't been doing it very long.  So how do I send something from say the `action` of a `<form>` element?  Do I have to do rewrite rules in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: No. ASP.Net MVC coupled with the default web.config will handle that all for you.

Comment: @mituw16 Are the rewrites in the web.config?

Comment: No. There are no rewrites per say like you would find in an apache .htaccess file. The urls are handled by .net's MVC routing engine. In MVC5 and below, this is handled in the RouteConfig.cs file. In .Net Core you configure these in your Startup class.

Comment: @mituw16 I know it is up to me to keep reading, but what happens to the URL in the action of a form element?  The browser is going to send it with ?var1=x&var2=y..., so how does it get turned into ASP.NET MVC friendly to the Router can parse it?

Comment: So say you have a controller say `HomeController` and an action in that controller named  and an action called `Test` In your form element you would do something like `<form action='home/test'>` .. Then when the form is submitted the MVC routing engine will route the request to the appropriate controller/action and it will also automatically bind any form data to a ViewModel object if you have set it up that way. If you don't want to use model binding you could just access the request data directly, but there's no legitimate reason for that. Standard and best practice is to use model binding.